# Двумерный массив uchar в QImage

Tags: qt, qimage

Есть двумерный массив uchar содержащий только два значения - 0 и 255 (белый и черный цвет, соответственно). Необходимо преобразовать данный массив в изображение. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если задача требует рисования чего-либо (текста в том числе) на изображении или даже просто вывод изображения на виджете, то необходимо использовать подходящий для этого в Qt формат. В обратном случае производительность будет проседать, так как если желаемое и нарисуется, то всё равно прозрачно будут выполняться конвертации изображения из одного формата в другой.

В Qt оптимальными форматами для рисования являются `QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied` (при необходимости в альфа-канале), `QImage::Format_RGB32` и `QImage::Format_RGB16`. Растровый движок Qt умеет рисовать изображения этих форматов непосредственно.

Другие форматы, включая `QImage::Format_Indexed8`, `QImage::Format_Grayscale8` и прочие, в задаче с рисованием лучше рассматривать как промежуточные и использовать их только при невозможности самостоятельно привести исходные данные в соответствующий оптимизированным форматам вид.

Все восьмибитные форматы в Qt используют таблицу цветов (т.н. палитру) и хранят в данных изображения для каждого пикселя лишь индексы, сооответствующие данным в палитре. Только для 32-х битных форматов значения пикселей хранятся непосредственно в данных изображения.

Если палитра не специфическая, то её создание обычно сводится к добавлению значений от `0` до `255`, где-нибудь сразу после получения изображения из исходных данных:

```
// Одномерный массив исходных данных изображения.
uchar *data = ...;

// Ширина и высота изображения в пикселях.
int width = 320;
int height = 240;

// Количество байт в одной строке изображения.
// Для одноканальных восьмибитных изображений этот параметр
// будет равен ширине в пикселях.
int stride = 320;

// Для трёхканальных - width * 3.
// int stride = 320 * 3;

QImage img(data, width, height, stride, QImage::Format_Indexed8);

// Создание таблицы цветов.
QVector<QRgb> color_table;
for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    color_table->append(qRgb(i,i,i));

img.setColorTable(color_table);

// Конвертация изображения в оптимальный для рисования формат.
QImage optimal_img = img.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB32);
```

Разумеется, что `optimal_img` будет занимать больший объём памяти, нежели чем если бы оно было в изначальном формате, однако рисование на нём или даже просто вывод на экран будут производиться значительно быстрее.

Не все форматы изображений могут быть сконвертированы в Qt из одного в другой. В этом случае потребуется использовать промежуточные.

Comment: Спасибо. Тут возникла ещё одна трудность, при попытке сохранить изображение в формате Format_Indexed8 - программа вылетает с ошибкой. если же преобразовать, как написано у Вас, к формату Format_RGB32, то всё сохраняется ( сохраняю через  QImageWriter). В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @bronstein87, вероятно потому что `Format_Indexed8` не поддерживается в качестве исходного при сохранении в один из файловых форматов, вроде png, jpg и других. Вам нужно использовать метод `QImageWriter::canWrite()` для проверки того, поддерживается ли текущий формат при сохранении изображения в файл, чтобы избежать краха приложения. Если метод вернёт `false`, то переводить изображение в иной формат. Ну или как вариант писать самостоятельно реализацию сохранения в файл кастомного формата.

Answer (score 2):

[Вот этот конструктор](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimage.html#QImage-4)

```
QImage::QImage(uchar * data, int width, int height, Format format)
```

Формат поставьте `QImage::Format_Indexed8`

Comment: Надо только ещё двумерный массив в одномерный завернуть, ну и палитру должным образом настроить.

Comment: Спасибо. Единственное, что не очень понимаю. В документации есть замечание  `Note: Drawing into a QImage with QImage::Format_Indexed8 is not supported`. Т.е это означает, что я не смогу воспользоваться,например, методом `void QPainter::drawText` для данного формата изображения? Просто мне нужно нанести надписи на полученные изображения...

Comment: И ещё один момент. А что на счёт формата `QImage::Format_Grayscale8`? По идее он тоже должен подойти. Не могу понять, для него палитра задается таким же образом?